# Uniqueness of the limit sequence of discrete probability measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $N_n$ be a sequence of natural numbers increasing to infinity, and suppose we have a sequence of finite sets of distinct points 
$X_n = \{x_1^{n},x_2^{n},\ldots,x^{n}_{N_n}\} \subset[0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$.  Consider the discrete probability measure
$$
\rho_n = \frac{1}{N_n}\sum_{i=1}^{N_n}\delta_{x^{n}_i},
$$
a normalized sum of delta functions centered at the points $x^{n}_i$. Being bounded as a linear operator on $C([0,1])$, there exists a vaguely convergent subsequence of the $\rho_n$ i.e. there exists a probability measure $\rho$ on [0,1] such that
$$
\int_0^1fd\rho_{n_k} \to_{k\to \infty} \int_0^1 fd\rho 
$$
for all $f \in C([0,1])$. 
Let me further impose a spacing condition that if 
$$
r_n := \inf_{i\neq j} |x^n_i - x^n_j|
$$
is the minimum distance between distinct pairs of the $x^n_i$, then
$$
\inf_n N_n r_n > 0.
$$
(in particular, this implies $x^n_i$ are distinct). This loosely can be interpreted as enforcing that the $X_n$ not accumulate too much on 0-dimensional sets (or perhaps I should say on sets of Hausdorff/Minkowski dimension < 1?  I'm not sure and would be interested in answers to this as well, though it's not my main question).

As a simple example, if $X_n$ is regularly spaced on $[0,1]$, then $d\rho = dx = $ Lebes**g**ue measure.

My question is:
What further conditions can be imposed on the sets $X_n$ to guarantee that the original sequence $\rho_n$ converges (as opposed to a subsequence)?

Note that this is a rewrite of an earlier question of mine (my first ever), since closed ([Uniqueness of the limit of a sequence of (discrete) probability measures](https://mathoverflow.net/q/326635/137640)).  I understand if it gets closed again, because it's pretty specific yet open-ended at the same time.  I imagine any nontrivial answer would be kind of creative, perhaps involving a rule or algorithm for how the points in the $X_n$ are distributed, and/or involving some nestedness property.  Nestedness alone (i.e. $X_n \subset X_{n+1}$) does not guarantee uniqueness of the limit, as I have constructed counterexamples to demonstrate.

Comment: At some point, you'll need to rule out the situation where $X_{2n}$ consists of $n$ points uniformly distributed in $[0;1/2]$ and $X_{2n+1}$ consists of $n$ points in $[1/2;1]$. More generally, if two sequences converge to two different limits and satisfy your assumptions, a mixture as described above will have two limit points and still satisfy your criteria.

Comment: If the inf equals $c>0$, then your condition says that any limit point $\rho$ is ac with respect to Lebesgue measure with density $\le 1/c$. Conversely, all such prob measures are possible as limit points. I don't think there will be a useful criterion how to read off convergence from the points that is not near tautological.

Comment: If  the measure $\rho$ is the arcsine measure, then such conditions can be formulated. Let 
$\hat I_n=\prod_{x,y \in X_n,  x \ne y}{|x-y|}^{\frac{1}{N_n(N_n-1)}}$. If $\lim_{n \to \infty} \hat I_n =  e^{-1/4}$, then $\rho_n \to \rho$ vaguely. This is because $\rho$ is the (unique) measure with minimal logarithmic energy on $[0,1]$ (viewed as a subset of the complex plane) and $1/4$ is the value of this minimal energy. The numbers $I_n$ can be thought of as ``discrete energies".

Comment: @MargaretFriedland: Except that this has unbounded density, so can't be the limit when the points $x_n$ satisfy the OP's assumptions.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Excellent point re absolute continuity with respect to Lebesgue measure.  I was aware of this, but I'm impressed you figured it out as fast as you did.

Comment: Starting with the comment of Remling if $\rho$ is a limit point, then $d\rho = fd\lambda$ for some $f \geq c > 0$. Put $F(t) := \int_0^t f(x)dx$, then $F$ continuous, strictly increasing with $F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1$ and image measure $\rho^T = \lambda$. Apply $F$ to the double sequence $x_i^n$. Then for this transformed sequence $\rho_n \to \lambda$. For this case f.i. the condition $\liminf_{n \to \infty} N_n r_n = 1$ is sufficient (not necessary). Then apply the backtransformation $F^{-1}$ and translate the conditions for the special case.

Answer (score 4):

For this answer the assumption that the points $x_i^n$ are distinct is not necessary. The restriction to $[0,1]$ is also not necessary. The answer applies to probability measures with finite support on any complete metric space.

On the set of Borel probability measures on $[0,1]$, the topology in question is given by the Kantorovich-Rubinshtein metric $d_0$. See V.I. Bogachev, "Measure theory", Chapter 8, or the Wikipedia article ["Wasserstein metric"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric).  In this metric the set of probability measures is complete. So a sequence converges if and only if it is Cauchy.

The Kantorovich-Rubinshtein metric is the optimal transport metric. The distance $d_0(\rho,\sigma)$ is the least cost of moving some divisible matter from a state distributed according to $\rho$ to one distributed according to $\sigma$, when the cost of moving a unit amount from $x\in[0,1]$ to $y\in[0,1]$ is the distance $|x-y|$.

If the distributions $\rho$ and $\sigma$ have finite support, every transport plan for moving from $\rho$ to $\sigma$ has a simple description: There are an integer $K>0$, elements $y_1,y_2,...,y_K$ in the support of $\rho$ and $z_1,z_2,...,z_K$ in the support of $\sigma$, and numbers
$\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_K \in[0,1]$ such that 
$\rho = \sum_{i=1}^K \alpha_i \delta_{y_i}$,
$\sigma = \sum_{i=1}^K \alpha_i \delta_{z_i}$,
and the plan moves amount $\alpha_i$ from $y_i$ to $z_i$ for $i=1,2,...,K$.
The cost of such a plan is 
$\sum_{i=1}^K \alpha_i |y_i - z_i |$.

The sequence of $\rho_n$ converges if and only if it is Cauchy.
So this is a **necessary and sufficient** condition for it to converge:

$(1) \;\; \forall \varepsilon>0 \;\exists M \;\forall m,n > M \;\exists K=K(m,n)
\;\exists y_1,y_2,...,y_K,z_1,z_2,...,z_K \in[0,1]$
$\exists \alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_K\in[0,1]
\;\;\rho_m = \sum_{i=1}^K \alpha_i \delta_{y_i} , 
\;\;\rho_n = \sum_{i=1}^K \alpha_i \delta_{z_i}, \;\;
\sum_{i=1}^K \alpha_i |y_i - z_i | < \varepsilon$.

From this one can derive various **sufficient** conditions, depending on what one desires. For example, in the following condition for $n>m$ the amount 
$\frac{1}{N_m}$ at each point of $X_m$ is split into $\frac{N_n}{N_m}$ equal parts and each of those parts is transported to one point of $X_n$.
(Of course this is only possible if $N_m$ divides $N_n$.)

$(2) \;\; \forall \varepsilon>0 \;\exists M \;\forall n>m > M 
\;\exists y_1,y_2,...,y_{N_n} \in[0,1]$
$\rho_m = \frac{1}{N_n}\sum_{i=1}^{N_n} \delta_{y_i}, 
\;\frac{1}{N_n}\sum_{i=1}^{N_n} |x_i^n - y_i | < \varepsilon$.

A variation of condition (2) may be useful when the sets $X_n$ form the levels of a tree in which each point in $X_{n+1}$ has exactly one parent in $X_n$ (for example, a nearest point in $X_n$) and each point in $X_n$ has the same number of children in $X_{n+1}$. The transport plan then follows the edges of the tree. For $n>m$ and $x\in X_n$, denote by $A_m(x)$ the unique ancestor of $x$ in $X_m$ (reached through a chain of parents). The following sufficient condition for the convergence of $\rho_n$ is a special case of (2):

$(3) \;\; \forall \varepsilon>0 \;\exists M \;\forall n>m > M 
\;\;\frac{1}{N_n}\sum_{i=1}^{N_n} |x_i^n - A_m(x_i^n) | < \varepsilon$.

Comment: why is the suggested "transport plan" from $\rho_m$ to $\rho_n$ the optimal one? There are many possible choices of $\alpha_i$, $y_i$ and $z_i$.

Comment: @Skeeve Thank you. I have edited the wording.

Comment: OK, but then it is only sufficient, necessity not evident. Actually it would be nice if you add some details and write an explicit formula for the Kantorovich-Rubinstein metric between $\rho_n$ and $\rho_m$. Maybe sorting $y_i$ and $z_i$ would help.

Comment: @Skeve The cost of the optimal transport plan is $<\varepsilon$ if and only if there exists a plan whose cost is $<\varepsilon$.

Comment: sorry, but if there exists a plan whose cost is $<\varepsilon$ then how do we know that this is *exactly* the plan which moves $y_i$ to $z_i$?

Comment: @Skeeve I added more details to the answer. I don't know if that answers your question.

Comment: @user95282 Excellent re that tree idea, that may be just what I need, and thank you for such a clear, thorough and informative response!

Answer (score 2):

Let $F_n$ be the distribution function of $\rho_n$. Then $F_n(0-) = 0$ and $F_n(1)$. Let $\rho$ be any limit point (w.r.to the weak topology) of $(\rho_n)_{n \in N}$ with distribution function $F$. Then there is a subsequence $(F_{n_k})_{k \in N}$ s.t. $F_{n_k}$ converges weakly to $F$, i.e. $\lim_{k \to \infty} F_{n_k}(t) = F(t)$ for each continuity point $t$ of $F$. If in particular $F$ is continuous (as implied by the spacing conditions, Remark of Christian Remling), then this convergence is uniform, i.e.
\begin{eqnarray}
(*) \lim_{k \to \infty} \|F_{n_k} - F\|_\infty = 0.
\end{eqnarray}
Thus if we know that any possible limit distribution $\rho$ has a continuous distribution function $F$, then this limit distribution function $F$ is uniquely defined if and only if
\begin{eqnarray}
(**) \lim_{m,n \to \infty} \|F_n - F_m\|_\infty = 0.
\end{eqnarray}
Note that here $F_n$ may be discountinuous. Of course this condition can be translated into conditions for the origninal $X_n$. Note that $N_n \cdot F_n(t)$ is the number of points $x_i^n$ in $[0,t]$.